# How to add an user inserted number of slots into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know that if I use `anyList = []*10` it will create a list with 10 slots, but I want to create a list with `x` slots, `x` being a number that the user created.

For example:

```
anylist = []

num = int(input())
```

If the user enters 4, I want the list `anyList` to have 4 empty slots.

Comment: _"I know that if I use `anyList = []*10` it will create a list with 10 slots"_ Your knowledge is wrong. An empty list is still an empty list when concatenated 10 times. Also, python doesn't have lists with "empty slots", so what do you actually want to get as a result?

Comment: `[]*10` is just an empty list `[]`.  Lists don't really have slots, you can keep adding items with `anyList.append(item)`

Comment: You can initially put None and then change it

Comment: But I dont want the number of thins to be kept on the list to be greater than the number inserted by the user.

If it inserts the number 4, I want the list "anyList" to store only 4 things that will be added later by other commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a list with empty slots in Python.  The closest thing you will get is to pre-fill a list with null values:

```
>>> num = int(input())
4
>>> [None] * num
[None, None, None, None]
```

This will allow `list.__setitem__` at indices 0, 1, 2, 3.

By the way, there is a third-party implementation of `defaultlist` that might interest you [here](https://github.com/c0fec0de/defaultlist), or you might be able to simply use the `collections.defaultdict` in the first place.

Comment: I think to answer OP's question, replace `4` with `num`.

Comment: Well, it's what I wanted.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

> I know that if I use `anyList = [] * 10` it will create a list with 10 slots.

This is in fact *incorrect*. If you write `somelist * somenumber`, it will construct a list with as length the length of `somelist` times `somenumber`, and it will repeat the list. For example:

```
>>> [1, 'a', 2, 5] * 3
[1, 'a', 2, 5, 1, 'a', 2, 5, 1, 'a', 2, 5]
```

But the above definition thus hints that an empty list (that has length zero) times any number, is just an empty list.

There are no "empty" slots in Python (well there are no empty slots at all in most programming languages). Most programming languages will write a default value as initial values to an array or list that is constructed. Other languages like C++, will not write a default value to the list, but will simply interpret what is at that moment in memory (so if by accident the memory had the number `1425` at that location, then the array/list contains that number).

So we need to decide what initial value to use. We can for instance use a `None`, a `4`, or anything else. Let us here use `None`.

Now to answer the question in general, we can multiply it with any integral number. So we can ask the user for input, convert it to an `int`, and then multiply the list with that number. For example:

```
d = int(input('Initial length?'))
our_list = [None] * d
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it clarified the topic to me!
I tought I could create empty slots in a list because if I write `anyList = [""] *4`  it will create this list: `["", "", "", ""]`